# Advanced .NET Generics, and where to start?

Tags: c#

I have been reviewing C# code that has a lot of generics (and generics with generics...) and its taking me longer to grok the code.

I know the gang of four patterns, and I know some of the fowler enterprise patterns (learning them as I go).

1. Are there any techniques you could suggest when tackling understanding systems like this?
2. Are there any resources on developing systems like this?

Comment: _"Are there any resources..."_ - Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

A generic is essentially a ***type parameter.***

**Type** - a class, struct or enum.

**Parameter** - something you pass into a method.

So a type parameter is a type that you pass into a method.  Why is this important?  Why not just pass `object` variables around?  For a couple of reasons.

1. Using a type parameter instead of an `object` avoids boxing.
2. Using a type parameter preserves static type safety, and allows type inference.

Beyond that, there isn't a lot to say.  *You have to think in terms of what can be done with objects generically*, without having to think about their type.

Can you put them in a list, without regards to their type?  Sure you can.  Since the list takes objects of all the same type, the type of the list is determined by how you create the list, and the type is determined at that time.  For example:

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

creates a list of strings.

Can you sort the items in the list?  Of course, as long as the type you specify when you create the list implements the `IComparable` interface.

```
list.Sort();
```

works because String implements `IComparable`.

Naturally, you can have composite types in a list:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, MyClass>>();
```

or recursive types

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public List<Node<T>> Children { get; set; }
}
```